# Default permissions for partition

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, lubuntu

I messed up one of my partitions with chmod and setfacl commands . I want to undo all these commands .

I need normal ntfs volume default permissions . I'm running dual boot win10-lubuntu .

Chmod no longer works . Probably cause of chmod g+s .

```
    root@nec-PC:/mnt# chmod 755 -c 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    mode of '01CFD131F13B1EE0' changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
    root@nec-PC:/mnt# chmod 755 -c 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    mode of '01CFD131F13B1EE0' changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
    root@nec-PC:/mnt# chmod 755 -c 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    mode of '01CFD131F13B1EE0' changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
    root@nec-PC:/mnt#
```

and on , and on but doesn't change anything .

edit: target partition has no OS installed .

History:

```
    276  chmod 755 01CFD131F13B1EE8
    277  chmod 755 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    278  ls
    279  cd 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    280  ls
    281  cd New folder
    282  ls
    283  cd ..
    284  cd mnt
    285  ls
    286  chmod 755 -R 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    287  man ls
    288  ls
    289  chmod g+s 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    290  setfacl
    291  setfacl -d -m g::rwx
    292  setfacl -d -m g::rwx 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    293  setfacl -d -m o::rx 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    294  getfacl 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    295  ls
    296  sudo setfacl -d -m o::rx 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    297  getfacl 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    298  chmod g+s 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    299  setfacl -d -m g::rwx 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    300  setfacl -d -m o::rx 01CFD131F13B1EE0
    301  getfacl 01CFD131F13B1EE0
```

This is pretty much it . As you may have noticed i'm not very good at these stuff .

Comment: Not sure what the permissions would be but may help if you look at the command history and provide a glimpse of what you did.

Comment: This may help: [How do I use chmod on an NTFS or FAT32 Partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: @Owen hines `sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever` i tried this one both ways , no errors but no help either permission for files stuck 777 cannot get it back to 755 i need to undo chmod g+s somehow

Comment: Can you access the files on the NTFS partition outside of the Ubuntu OS? For example, can you boot into it?

Comment: There is no OS in it . In windows i couldnt use files until i messed it up with setfacl . Now i have no issue using them but i'm afraid about setting it to 777 .

Comment: Wait, so is there a bootable OS on the partition or just files?

Comment: Just files , it's in the edit but typed late sorry .

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any apps on linux to solve it . I just used permissions time machine lite program on windows and that fixed all errors .

http://www.amydprojects.com/2013/10/permissions-time-machine-v14.html